# AngularJS $http post to geoserver get feature

Tags: angularjs, http-post, geoserver, web-feature-service

I'm building a WFS client service in Angular for geoserver. So far I used $http GET to retrieve features, but the cql_filter is sometimes to big and http GET does not work because of a too big URL. Could you help me translate the following http GET into an http POST? I would prefer to use CQL filtering instead of OGC if possible, since I have it implemented already.
Here's my getFeature method:

```
this.getWfsFeature = function(typeName, filter){

    var deffered = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: ConfigService.getGeoserverURL() + "/frqaim/ows",
        params: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            cql_filter: filter,
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: typeName,
            maxFeatures: 60,
            outputFormat:'application/json'
        },
    }).success(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data.features);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var msg = 'could not get wfs features. status: ' + status;
        console.log(msg);
        deffered.reject(msg);
    });

    return deffered.promise;
}
```

This is my trial:

```
this.getWfsFeature2 = function(typeName, filter){

    var deffered = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: ConfigService.getGeoserverURL() + "/frqaim/ows",
        data: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            cql_filter: filter,
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: typeName,
            maxFeatures: 60,
            outputFormat:'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data.features);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var msg = 'could not get wfs features. status: ' + status;
        console.log(msg);
        deffered.reject(msg);
    });

    return deffered.promise;
}
```

Response exception:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8081/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
 <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
  <ows:ExceptionText>org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) 
 only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) </ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
   </ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I would like to create the "data" xml that gives the same result as the GET request.

Fix:

THis is how the post looks like:

```
  <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" request="getFeature"    outputFormat="application/json"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
<wfs:Query typeName="typeName">
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:And>
<ogc:Within>
<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates>-62,48.30519115013797 -62,56.525823385131694 -30,56.525823385131694 -30,48.30519115013797 -62,48.30519115013797        </gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</ogc:Within>

<ogc:Or>
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>propName</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>value</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyName>propName</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>value</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Or>
<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyName>valid_to</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Function name="dateParse">
    <ogc:Literal>yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>2015-03-06T09:47:46.260Z</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
<ogc:PropertyName>valid_from</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Function name="dateParse">
    <ogc:Literal>yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>2015-03-06T10:47:46.260Z</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
</ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
</ogc:And>
</ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: what does the post you actually send look like

Comment: I've updated the question with the post. The only problem I'm still trying to fix is date parsing in ISO format. Any ideeas? Error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date, could not parse
Invalid date, could not parse
Unparseable date: &quot;2015-03-06T09:47:46.260Z&quot;

Comment: Just the literal date should work.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out the problem? I am seeing exactly the same issue. I mean the withe space message.